# Environment for implementing/testing Computer Graphics algorithms

Tags: python, computational-geometry, computer-vision, geometry

I need to code up a computer graphics algorithm for Surface Registration.

Briefly **surface registration** is the process of finding "optimal" one-one correspondence 
between surfaces, where the meaning of optimal depends on the specific problem.

I do not have much experience with Computer Graphics software, and so I was looking around
the web for a good software environment to code my algorithm up in.

One promising option I hit upon was [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), which to my delight also has a Python interface to it.

My questions are

1. Is *Blender + Python* a good software environment for implementing and testing computer graphics algorithms?
2. If not, are there better alternatives to it (hopefully using a Pythonic interface)?
3. Are there any particular points from your experience
   which I should keep in mind while using Blender (or whatever package you recommend) while implementing/testing my algorithm?

Comment: There is actually a blender.stackexchange.com, where you would likely get much better and more experienced answers.  I will flag this and see if migration may be possible/right for this question.

Comment: This question is a cross-post of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/environment-for-implementing-testing-computer-graphics-algorithms.